# Regex not matching words ending with "Impl"

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I want to create a regex that allows only class names not ending with `Impl`. I'v read that "not ends with" could be tested with a negative lookahead `(?!)`, but I cannot find a working (Java) regex.

I tried

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]*?(?!Impl)
```

but it matches `SomeImpl`, what shouldn't be the case.

What regex wouldn't match class names ending with `Impl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A negative lookahead wont work because - with the `*?` (lazy zero-or-more) quantifier - it'll check at `S` and find no `Impl` immediately ahead so the match succeeds.

If you changed to a greedy quantifier (change `*` to `*?`) it would still fail because you would be at the end of the string - there is no "ahead" to look at.

Instead you want to **use a negative look*behind*** to check the previous content, i.e.

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]*(?<!Impl)
```

*(You may or not want `$` at the end of that, depending on where the pattern is used)*

<sub>Side note: not directly relevant here, but useful to know is that (in Java regex) a lookbehind must have a limited width - you can't use `*` or `+` quantifiers, and must instead use limited numerical quantifiers, e.g. `{0,99}`</sub>

But unless the pattern itself is important (or you're working in a context where you must use regex), a **simpler option would be [String.endsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29)**, like so:

```
! mystring.endsWith('Impl')
```

Comment: super observation buddy +1

Comment: aelor, I've just updated my explanation on why the lookahead fails - does it make sense?

Comment: but i used to know that a lazy quantifier matches the least. `.*` should only match till the end ?

Comment: `String.endsWith` is not an option in my case, because I need the pattern to configure IntelliJ IDEA inspections.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - a `.*` will match until the end then backtrack if necessary, whilst `.*?` will do one character at a time, unless a later backtrack requires it to consume more.