# extract only words that do not contain words ending with a particular letter combination (using regex only)

Tags: regex, grep, extract, cpu-word, text-manipulation

I have this list of Portuguese language words https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pythonprobr/palavras/master/palavras.txt. I want to extract only words that do not end in "er" or "ar". I have been trying to apply the methods in the answers to this question [Regex not matching words ending with "Impl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964598/regex-not-matching-words-ending-with-impl) but I can't make it work.
I've been using the command like this from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964675/10824251 : `$ grep -oP '[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]*(\?<! er) [ [A-Z] [A-Za-z \\ d] * (\? <! er)] ' palavra.txt > output.txt`

Comment: What language or tool or regex engine do you use to do that?

Comment: I've been using the command like this from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964675/10824251 : `$ grep -oP '[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]*(\?<! er) [ [A-Z] [A-Za-z \\ d] * (\? <! er)] ' palavra.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Use `grep -v '[ea]r$' palavra.txt > output.txt`. I believe you want to get all *lines* that do not end with `er` and `ar`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thankx! It worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all lines that do not end with `er` and `ar`, you may use

```
grep -v '[ea]r$' palavras.txt > output.txt
```

NOTES:

- `-v` - inverts the result, we get all the lines that do not match the regex
- `[ea]r$` - matches `e` or `a`, then `r` at the end of the string